# gcc compilation and Make file error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a directory called "aos" in which i have the results of the make, namely .o file and .a file.

My test case file in a directory called "test1" which is under the "aos" directory.

I am in the test1 directory which has a file called main.c (this is the file I want to execute). I tried compiling the file by giving the command

```
 gcc -Wall -pedantic -I ../gtthreads.c -o main main.c ../gtthreads.a
```

But I get these errors:

```
../gtthreads.c is not a directory  
../gtthreads.a is not a directory
```

What am i doing wrong here? How do I refer to the .a file and .c files which are in "aos" directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-I` and `-L` switches are used to add directories to the `#include` and linker search paths respectively. So if you have headers in the parent directory, but include them without relative paths in your code, you can use:

```
-I..
```

which will make `gcc` look in the parent directory for headers.

If you want to compile `main.c`, and `gtthreads.c` from the parent directory into an executable, you can:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -I.. ../gthreads.c main.c -o main
```

If you want to compile `main.c` and link it with the `gthreads.a` file in the parent directory, just use:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -I.. -o main main.c ../gtthreads.a
```